# combobox searched of first index item on form load event.how i can stop the searching on form load event

Tags: vb.net

i search name on the basis of combobox.combobox load correctly on form load event but it select first item on form load event and also search on the basis of first item.how i can stop this selection on form load event ???

i use combobox1.selectedindex=-1. this show no item in combobox but search on the basis of first item of combobox...

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    MyBase.Load
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "data source=abc;initial 
        catalog=LoginDB;integrated security=true"
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "search_data"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim dset As New DataSet
        Dim dpt As New SqlDataAdapter
        dpt.SelectCommand = cmd
        dpt.Fill(dset, "tab")
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dset.Tables("tab")
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID"
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As 
    EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        cmd.CommandText = "show_date"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        p = New SqlParameter
        p.ParameterName = "@id"
        p.Value = ComboBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)

        Dim dset As New DataSet
        Dim dpt As New SqlDataAdapter
        dpt.SelectCommand = cmd
        dpt.Fill(dset, "tab")
        If dset.Tables("tab").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        nameTextBox.Text = dset.Tables("tab").Rows(0)("name")
        End If
    End Sub
```

i want that when form load then no searching and when user change the item then it searching...

Comment: Well, in `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`, the first line should be: `if ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return`. Or use the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead, using `ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)` instead of `ComboBox.Text` (you should use this method in any case).

Comment: thank you....it is working well